# What exercises do pianists use to get used to a new piano?

Tags: piano

What exercises do pro pianists play (if any) when playing on a new unfamiliar concert hall piano with an unfamiliar or uncomfortable key action?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking for techniques used to identify keys which don't feel comfortable?

Comment: Different pianos have different key weights (particularly grands if you're used to an upright, etc.).  If you play for a while then your muscle memory can get used to this keyboard, but I think the question is "are there any exercises to play that get you used to it faster".

Comment: I have edited to make that clearer. Kvas, if that isn't what you meant please edit.

Comment: If it's me, I'd play scales and arpeggios, particularly chromatics, then just get on with the pieces in question. Pedals need familiarising, too.

Comment: For my part (but I'm not a professional), I often play fast repetitions of a single note to check the mechanics of the keys. For a more general feeling of how the new instrument behaves, scales are certainly always good. You could also play piano (in a dynamical sense) chords of multiple notes if you want to know whether all keys react similarly to you pressing them.

Answer (score 3):

I find that most pianos are within an acceptable, familiar range such that I don't need to do anything to get used to them. I'll play a little bit of whatever I'm there to play, and if it feels too far off from normal, then I might run a few technical bits. If there's nothing suitable from the material I'm there to play, two things I have in my back pocket are:

1. Mozart piano sonata K545 (C major). A nice tour of basic technique--alberti bass, scales, trills, and arpeggios before you even hit the development.
2. Debussy's Arabesque No. 1. A relatively easy piece that I have in muscle memory, but which requires delicate touch and careful pedaling. This gives me a really good sense of the sustain and the weight of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

I played jazz professionally for a few years, and in instances where I played on an unfamiliar piano (as opposed to a familiar piano or my own keyboard), I wouldn't always have time to warm up on that piano. But when I did have that time, something I found helpful was to take a jazz bebop melody and play it very slowly--at 70 bpm or 80 bpm--through all 12 keys. Then I would increase the metronome a few ticks to 82 bpm or 83 bpm and go through all 12 keys again. I would continue going through all 12 keys, increasing by 1-3 bpm each time, until I was up to ~120 bpm. This exercise would take about 2-3 hrs. If I didn't have that kind of time, I might increase the metronome two or three times as often, such that I increased the bpm after every 6 keys or after every 4 keys rather than after every 12 keys.

In my own practicing, I would dedicate ~20 hrs/week on these exercises, using a variety of different tunes. Circumstances required me to practice on different pianos with different actions. These exercises helped me discern very small inaccuracies in my playing and in my rhythmic placement of notes. That's where my attention was when doing the exercises: at the beginning of this time in my life, my playing was decent enough that I could listen for instances where I missed the click/beat by small fractions of a second. This ability improved as I spent more time with these exercises, because this practice technique is designed to improve one's precision. At 82 bpm, beats occur about 0.03 s more frequently than at 82 bpm. It took a lot of work and focus for me to be able to control my fingers to strike the piano at exactly the correct hundredth of a second that a particular tempo demanded.

In turn, I think this practice helped me be more flexible and more capable of adjusting quickly to an unfamiliar piano during a performance setting. Muscle memory confers benefit to the performer by allowing her to turn control of her hands over to automatic functions in her brain. The more automatic she becomes (through practice), the more freedom she has to think/focus her attention on other things, perhaps including the unfamiliar action of a piano. In addition, practicing at different tempos might effectively *simulate* different piano actions which require slower/faster hand movement. And maybe practicing in different keys effectively simulates different amounts of resistance, since different keys require different hand positions which produce different tensions in the fingers. These may not be the *exact* reasons why it's beneficial to practice in different keys and tempos. But even if I have the details wrong, I do still think playing a song in different keys and tempos helps because it gives the performer a much more versatile muscle/kinesthetic memory that covers a much wider range of experiences. This is exactly what's required when sitting at an unfamiliar piano with an unfamiliar action.

Comment: I love this answer. I'm going to "borrow" this practice. Thank you!